# Undefine property when trying to access data from another table in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have user table and profile table. In my profile table i put the user Avatar. so i try to get those Avatar by making this function into my User Model:

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}

public function getAvatar()
{
    if ($this->profile()->avatar){
        return Storage::url($this->profile->avatar);
    }else{
        return Storage::url('public/avatars/default.jpg');
    }
}
```

and in my blade i'm accesing the function like this:

```
        <img src="{{ Auth::user()->getAvatar() }}" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
```

but it give me an error "Undefined property". The user have no Avatar and i'm expecting it will get the default.jpg, so what wrong with my code? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it has to do with the two different ways you get the avatar from your profile relation.

Your if statement
`$this->profile()->avatar`

Your return
`$this->profile->avatar`

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think the second is correct.

Comment: i do that at the first time and it give me this errors Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 2):

Change

`if ($this->profile()->avatar){`

to

`if ($this->profile->avatar){`

and it should work properly.

Comment: why the first one doesnt work while the latter is fine?

Comment: If you define a relationship in a Laravel the related Table becomes a property of the query object.
Maybe someone here can explain it better, my english skills are to bad for that Kind of explanation

Comment: I think the first line just returns the query object. It is useful if you want to add some further filtering like $this->profile()->where(...)
So the first line would work if you write $this->profile()->get()->avatar.

$this->profile->avatar is the recommended way here though

Comment: ^ `#get()` returns collection, so `#first()` might be better for this case. Thanks for explaining, btw.

Comment: i do that at the first time and it give me this errors Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: @Henra you have to make sure first if the related does exists from db `! is_null($this->profile) ? $this->profile->avatar : ''`